# He worked very hard but he failed to win the match. Can I delete the second 'he'?

Tags: ellipsis

He worked very hard but he failed to win the match.

Can I delete the second 'he'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The subject ***he*** will be understood. Where you have two verbs that have the same subject, and want to join them with a conjunction, you put the subject first, then the first verb and any objects and adverbs and so on, then the conjunction (here that is ***but***), and then the second verb with its objects and adverbs.

(Because I'm also a bit of a maths nerd, I think of that as the subject being *distributive* over the conjunction. No idea if that term is used in linguistics.)